# Как написать подсчет элементов не равных нулю?

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Есть программа подсчета нечетных элементов. Как написать подсчет элементов не равных нулю?

Turbo Assembler

```
mov ax, data 
mov ds, ax 

lea bx, mas ;берём в bx адрес первого элемента
mov cx, len ;счетчик цикла
xor ax, ax ;обнуляем регистр
cikl: mov al, [bx] ;прибавляем к al байт, адрес которого хранится в bx
test ax,1 ;проверяем на четность 
jnz next 
inc numb; увеличиваем, если четно
next:
inc bx ;переходим к следующему элементу 
loop cikl
```

Comment: Комментарии не соответствуют коду: `mov al, [bx]` не есть "прибавление", это присваивание. `test ax, 1` - это не проверка на чётность, это проверка на равенство единице.

Comment: @yeputons, `test ax, 1` - это проверка младшего бита на равенство единице. Так уж получилось, что у четных чисел младший бит равен 0, а у нечетных - 1. Так что это вполне себе проверка на четность.

Comment: ну например `or ax,ax` и перход по наличию/отсутствию флага Z

Comment: @insolor действительно, перепутал с `cmp`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Меняете проверку на четность на проверку на 0:

   ```
   test ax, ax ; эквивалентно cmp ax, 0, но в скомпилированном виде короче
   ```
2. После проверки должен быть переход, если проверка установила флаг Z (т.е. если нам попался нулевой элемент):

   ```
   jz next
   ```